# How to do BDE SetRange in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, bde

We're migrating from the BDE to SQL Server. (Thank goodness!!!)

Is the behavior of this code in the BDE:

```
var
    Table1: TTable;

...
    Table1.Open;
    Table1.SetRangeStart;
    Table1.FieldByName('Key1').AsInteger := 25;
    Table1.SetRangeStop;
    Table1.FieldByName('Key1').AsInteger := 30;
    Table1.KeyExclusive;
    Table1.ApplyRange
```

duplicated by the code below (ignoring that fact the both imply that the field named "Key1" is some sort of reliable order, which usually isn't the case with keys...)

```
Var
    Query: TADOQuery;

 ...
    Query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (Key1 > 25) AND (Key2 < 30)
    Query.Open;
```

Comment: You cannot migrate *from BDE to SQL Server* because BDE is a set of components whilst SQL Server is a DBMS. But to your question, I'd say it would rather be `...WHERE (Key1 >= 25) AND (Key2 <= 30)` as long as you don't set the `KeyExclusive` property to `True` (as mentioned on [`this page`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Specifying_Ranges#Including_or_excluding_records_that_match_boundary_values)). But I don't know the version of Delphi that you use, so it's difficult to say whether the `KeyExclusive` you have in your code is a method or a useless (property) statement.

Comment: @TLama is correct; the proper operators would be `>=` and `<=`. With that being said, it seems to me that a quick test of your query in SSMS would have answered this for you without a post here - surely you know what results you would get from the BDE operation, and a quick test of the query with the same data in SQL Server would tell you whether the results were the same or not, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, Ken, a test would've worked. Would you have you been more forgiving to a newcomer if I had posted that I done the test.  I was taught that although tests are useful, when one's in new to an environment, it's important to confirm that the observed behavior is actually *defined* behavior and that there aren't any lurking surprises that an expert would know but a novice might not.  My apologies for posting a question that you apparently feel I could've answered myself.

Comment: TLama, if you post your comment as an answer, I will flag it as such.